# Authorization Error 401 using GET in httr (R).

Tags: r, python-3.x, get, postman, httr

I'm trying to make a GET call in R using httr and I keep getting an authorization 401 error.
R code:

```
    testfunction2 <- function()
    {
        set_config(verbose())
        locus_url <- "https://api.locusenergy.com/v3/clients/5599"
        r <- GET(url = "https://api.locusenergy.com/v3/clients/5599",
                 query=list(authorization="Bearer c935845d8fc1124757e66ce04d2c75d0"),
         Accept="application/json")
    }
```

The results:

```
> print(testfunction2())
-> GET /v3/clients/5599
    authorization=Bearer%20c935845d8fc1124757e66ce04d2c75d0 HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.39.0 r-curl/0.9.1 httr/1.0.0
-> Host: api.locusenergy.com
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: AWSELB=D91FBFE1087EF6EBC125A126777051237474A8A060B6095B8E3C16151308453F8556B2A2E90CB2178F365FAA8AA8C29B124D15CA3EB859CFE615428E8D55C393ABB5B436BF
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
<- Content-Type: application/json
<- Date: Sun, 16 Aug 2015 05:02:27 GMT
<- Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
<- transfer-encoding: chunked
<- Connection: keep-alive
<-
```

I expect it to return a 200 code (rather than 401, that implies authorization error.)

I know the token is correct because it works if I use the Postman (google add-in) and Python.  The token won't work for you because I changed it since I can't share it.

Python Code:

```
    import http.client
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.locusenergy.com")
    headers = {
        'authorization': "Bearer 935845d8fc1124757e66ce04d2c75d0"
        }
    conn.request("GET", "/v3/clients/5599", headers=headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data)
```

results from Python

```
    b'{"statusCode":200,"partnerId":4202,"tz":"US/Arizona","firstName":"xxx","lastName":"xxxx","email":"xxxx@aol.com","id":5599}'
```

So, again the question is what am I doing wrong in R or can you give me any hints?  This won't be reproducible for you because the token expired and I can't share it.
Could it be the space in the authorization?  authorization="Bearer 935845d8fc1124757e66ce04d2c75d0"?  Are there any hints in the verbose output of the get call in R?

For reference, this is the site's API page:
https://developer.locusenergy.com/

The site requires OAUTH2 authentication to return the token.  I didn't include that code but I verified the token works with Python and Postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are passing your authorization values in the query string of the `httr` code and not in the http header as you are doing in the python code. Instead use

```
GET(url = "https://api.locusenergy.com/v3/clients/5599",
    accept_json(),
    add_headers(Authorization="Bearer c935845d8fc1124757e66ce04d2c75d0")
)
```

Comment: Thank you a hundred times over.  This makes perfect sense and works like a charm!